# Users as database users or user as a row in user table, audit table.

Tags: mysql, triggers, audit

So, I've been developing a web app and came to this issue...

I need to audit every change that's being made on database tables, but since I have just one database user but a lot of users in my user table, I don't see how can I save into the audit table the exact user who did the change (since I'm doing that with a mysql trigger, and the trigger saves which database user is logged in).

If I don't get to that point of detail, I won't be able, for example, to know which employee changed some data, I just would know that it was made by an employee.

What's the best approach to solve this?

Is it a good practice to have one database user per user?

Comment: Agreed with Ed below.  That is to say, your auditing needs to be at the application level, even if you're storing the audit logs in a database.

Comment: So, it means that I shouldn't be using triggers, that I need to manually save changes on database table. I don't think this is the best way either =/.

Comment: There may be packages written for your language/framework that automate most of it.  Audit logs are seldom fun to implement.  :/

Answer (score 0):

*Is it a good practice to have one database user per user?*

No

Have a table of users and mark items in the audit table with the users id (from the users table).

Comment: How do I tell the MYSQL trigger that the user is not the database user, that the user is the one that is active in the Session in PHP?
Is this possible?

Comment: You script uses one database user to access it. The user is at the application level.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote in the question. So?